# How to use VPN IP address in docker to Laravel App

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, vpn

I used Docker version[Version 2.0.0.0-mac81 (29211)] in Mac OSX.

Done setup to all my containers after running a container which is Laravel App, I check my IP Address.

```
"Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.18.0.4",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
```

So now, I want to change my IP Address using a VPN [FortiClient]. Is this setup possible?

Sorry in advance for the noob question, I really need your expertise.

Comment: I think this might help: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/issues/443

Comment: btw, if your vpn is configured to redirect all traffic from and to your machine, you won't need to do anything but exposing the container ports on your host.

Comment: @stefano I will check. Thanks!

Comment: @Stefano do you how to do that `redirect all traffic`? I want to try it!

Comment: you can simply check it by connecting to https://ifconfig.me/ then connect there again while using the vpn. If the address is different then very probably all your traffic is being redirected. I mean it's not granted but it's a good indicator. It mainly depends on your vpn client, setup and OS...